# How to call manually Response.Listener in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have the following method that runs some web services commands in Android.

```
    Response.Listener Success = new Response.Listener<JSONObject >() {@Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject  response) {
                    JSONObject  S = response;
                    // do something with the response
    }};
    
    Response.ErrorListener Fail = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == 400) {
                Success.notify();  // <<<<< According to some technical custom logic, this should be considered as a successful REST command. Hence run Success Response Listener
            }
            else {
                // operation failed, do something
            }
        }
    };

    JSONObject J = new JSONObject();        
    J.put("param", some parameters);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Act);
    JsonObjectRequest JsonRequestObject = new JsonObjectRequest(Method, URL, J, Success, Fail);        
    queue.add(JsonRequestObject);
```

According to some custom technical logic, the requests that get 400 as a response should be considered as successful and hence run the success callback.

I tried this code but it crashes at the line :

```
                Success.notify();  // <<<<<
```

How can I execute the Success call back manually?

Comment: i highly doubt you can, since you probably have no control over those callbacks. add in your own callback instead

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `notify()` you should call `onResponse()` like `Success.onResponse()` with `null` argument or with some `JSONObject` mapped from `error.networkResponse`.

More generalized way - create custom Response Listener (to listen to the success/error events in one place):

```
public abstract class ResponseListener<T> implements Response.Listener<T>,
        Response.ErrorListener {

    @Override
    public final void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == 400) {
            // redirect to onResponse()
            onResponse(null /* or some response T object mapped from [error.networkResponse] */);
        } else {
            onError(error);
        }
    }

    public abstract void onError(VolleyError error);
}
```

...

```
 final ResponseListener<JSONObject> responseListener =
            new ResponseListener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@Nullable JSONObject response) {
                    // do something with the response
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(VolleyError error) {
                    // operation failed, do something
                }
            };
    //
    final JsonObjectRequest JsonRequestObject =
            new JsonObjectRequest(Method, URL, J, responseListener, responseListener);
    //
```